# How do I change my code to improve the complexity?

Tags: python

Write a function pairs of sum(lst, s) that find all pairs of integers in an input list that sum to a specific value and that has a worst-case time complexity of O(nlogn) where n is the size of the input list.
The detailed input/output specification of the function is as follows.
I have to write a code which produces a better complexity O(n log n). The current code which I have written has a complexity of O(n^2).

```
def pairs_of_sum(lst, s):
    """ Finds pairs of list elements with specific sum.

    Input : list of unique integers (lst),
            integer (s)
    Output: list containing all pairs (x, y) of elements 
            of lst such that x < y and x + y = s

    For example:
    >>> pairs_of_sum([7, 1, 25, 10], 5)
    []
    >>> pairs_of_sum([7, 1, 25, 10], 32)
    [(7, 25)]
    >>> pairs = pairs_of_sum([-2, 4, 0, 11, 7, 13], 11)
    >>> set(pairs) == {(0, 11), (4, 7), (-2, 13)}
    True
    """
    a = sorted(lst)
    res = []

    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[i] + a[j] == s:
                res.append((a[i], a[j]))
    return res
```

This is my code. How do I change my code to improve the complexity to O(n log n)?

Comment: Read *books* like [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) then use a source code editor like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to change your code. Be aware that **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**. Perhaps reading about [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)s could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Loop over `a` once. Subtract each value from `s` to get the target value (the paired value that you'd add to the other value from `a` to make `s`). Use [the `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to locate said value in `a` in `O(log n)` time instead of the `O(n)` time required to do a linear search for it. Since you do the `O(log n)` step once for every value in `a` (`n` long), total work is `O(n log n)`.

That's the general algorithm, go forth and code.

I'll note, if you don't need to worry about duplicates, this could be done even faster by making a second conversion to make a `set` out of the input, to get `O(1)` lookups instead of `O(log n)` lookup, reducing overall work to `O(n)` (assuming you don't actually need to sort the input; maybe you do). And even if duplicates are involved, you could get the same algorithmic complexity by replacing `set` with `collections.Counter` and just repeating pairs a number of times equal to their count when the value occurs more than once.